# How to debug a Clojure file in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, la-clojure

No breakpoint can be set on line 5, which contains `[x]`.

IntelliJ won't let me do so. I used different plugin, such as [La Clojure](https://github.com/JetBrains/la-clojure/) and [Cursive](https://cursiveclojure.com/). Both stop at line 3 rather than line 5.

So, how people step into the code in Clojure?

Is there any syntax suggestion or maybe tool to help with?

```
(defn flattenlist
  ([x & more]
    (concat (if (vector? x)
              (apply flattenlist x)
              [x]
            )
            (if (= more nil)
              nil
              (apply flattenlist more))))
  )
(flattenlist [[1 [[2]]] 3 [4 5] 6])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, by convention, all trailing parentheses are on the same line, something like this:

```
(defn flattenlist
  ([x & more]
   (println x)
   (concat (if (vector? x)
             (apply flattenlist x)
             [x])
           (if (= more nil)
             nil
             (apply flattenlist more)))))

(flattenlist [[1 [[2]]] 3 [4 5] 6])
```

Secondly, when you use composable functions, it is easy to insert a println and run/test just that function because it is referentially transparent.  I am only a Clojure hobbyist, but I typically debug with printlns and unit tests.  Using breakpoints isn't really that reliable.

If you really want something similar to setting a breakpoint, you can try using [this debugging macro](https://coderwall.com/p/xayyvq) (not mine).

Comment: Yeah, I think printing is the right way to go. Ricky use the same ide as mine. Same position.